# How do I stop a flash error message from showing on page load until after button is clicked in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I'm trying to figure out a way to stop this flash message from showing on page load:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

   def index

     @users = User.search params[:search]
     @default_image = "/assets/default_avatar.jpg"
     if @users.empty? || params[:search].blank? 
        flash[:error] = "Sorry no user(s) found!" if @users.empty?
        flash[:error] = "Please give us something to search for!" if params[:search].blank?
        render 'index'
     end    
   end
end
```

I understand why it's showing (obviously when page is visited the search params is blank already). There must be some trick in ruby on rails that I can use on this flash message to stop it from firing until search button is clicked e.g.

```
flash[:error] = "Please give us something to search for!" if params[:search].blank? after_get
```

Bare in mind that was after_get was made up.

I'm sure someone out there has the answer for this.

I saw after_commit in the rails api but no example of how to use it in my situation or even if it's what I need.

Kind reards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to add a hidden field to the search form and check if that value is present instead of the actual search-string.

View

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :searching, true %>
```

Controller

```
flash[:error] = "Please give us something to search for!" if params[:searching]
```

Comment: I find it funny how this worked, it's such a simple solution. You must be a great problem solver. I used if params[:search].blank? && params[:searching] instead so that my other flash message would show if user typed in a non existent user. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help! I've actually think i have an even simpler solution that won't require a hidden field... You could check `params[:search].nil?`. That should be true if the request is not coming through the search form, and `params[:search].blank? && !params[:search].nil?` is true for an empty search.

Comment: That worked. Even better. Originally I did try params[:search].nil? but didn't think to use the result of that to y advantage the way you just did. This solution is better any way because I don't need the hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of java script based solution, (but not rails)

1. Print the rails flash message in a DIV
2. Keep that DIV hidden
3. When user clicks the search button, just use a java script to
   display the DIV

I think this fits your requirement, and as far as I'm concern rails doesnt support your requirement out of the box

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you access the action 'index' either with a GET request (in this case you don't want the flash message), or with a POST form where the :search field is filled.

You can check if you're in a POST request with `request.post?` (also exists `request.get?`, `request.put?`, etc...)

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

  def index       
    @default_image = "/assets/default_avatar.jpg"
    if request.post? 
       @users = User.search params[:search]
       if @users.empty? || params[:search].blank? 
         flash[:error] = "Sorry no user(s) found!" if @users.empty?
         flash[:error] = "Please give us something to search for!" if params[:search].blank? 
       end
    end    
  end
end
```

I removed the `render 'index'`, I think it's useless.

Comment: Didn't work for me.. using get. Flash message still shows when I visit page.

Comment: That would mean you get through the  `if request.post? ` statement, that's strange. The flash message can have been set somewhere else ?

Comment: I can tell this one is going to bug me for a while. Not sure what's going on.