# ruby on rails flash notice always appears

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, message, notice

I have a controller (not model related) which searches for stuff on YouTube via API. What I'm trying to achieve is simple enough...if someone clicks the search button when no string was entered then a flash notice will appear saying 'please enter search string'.

The 'main' view is as follows:

```
    <%= form_tag({:controller => 'main', :action => 'index'}, :method => 'get') do %>
        <%= label_tag(:text, 'Search:') %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:text) %>
        <%= submit_tag('Search') %>
    <% end %>

    <div id="flash">
        <% if flash.now[:notice] %>
            <p id="notice"><%= flash.now[:notice] %></p>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

My index action in my 'main' controller looks like this:

```
    def index
        if params[:text].blank?
        flash.now[:notice] = 'Please enter a search string'
        render 'index'
    else
        #do searches on YouTube
    end
```

I've looked at other question similar to this on stackoverflow as well and tried a few thing and still doesn't work. I've played around with using flash[] versus flash.now[] and still the notice message just sticks even when I first load the page. I might be missing something quite trivial here but I've spent a while figuring it out and still stuck. Anyway help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
Ok, I have found an answer. I simply added the following in my form in the view:

```
    <%= hidden_field_tag :searching, true %>
```

then i changed my controller to:

```
    flash.now[:notice] = 'Please enter a search string' if params[:searching]
```

This worked fine. This is courtesy of the answer here:
[How do I stop a flash error message from showing on page load until after button is clicked in ruby on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035908/how-do-i-stop-a-flash-error-message-from-showing-on-page-load-until-after-button)

FOLLOW UP QUESTION: in the link above, it suggested a cleaner answer which is to use:

```
    params[:search].blank? && !params[:search].nil?
```

However, this doesn't work for me. I get the error:

```
    undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm a newbie in Ruby so is this a syntactical error?

Comment: First thing, why do you call `render 'index'` explicitly? What exactly is your problem? Do you get the flash notice even if you call action with `params[:text]` being not-blank?

Comment: When you initially load the page, will there be a params[:text]?

Comment: Hi Marek, I've tried redirect_to but it gets stuck in a loop. Any reason why you ask why I use render 'index'? The problem is that the flash notice is permanently there. I also get the flash notice even when params[:text] is not blank. Sorry, I'm still pretty new to all this...

Comment: Hi Vimsha, when I first load the page, there will be no default value in the search box, hence, it will be blank. I've thought about that before but I thought that the method will only check to see if param[:text] is blank once I hit the search button?

Answer (score 0):

This may help, worth a try. In my case, my flash message was not shown because I was using

```
flash.now[:notice]
```

When changed to

```
flash[:notice]
```

started showing it.

Full code, controller:

```
  def create
    user_data = user_params
    user_data[:password] = SecureRandom.uuid
    @user = User.new(user_data)
    @user.save
    flash[:notice] = 'An email was sent for the user to confirm their account.'
    respond_with(@user)
  end
```

aaplication.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>

<body>
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div class="container">
  <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
    <div id=<%= message_type %> class="alert"><%= message %></div>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```